# Amazon RDS and VPC Endpoints Connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am having an Amazon RDS Postgres instance which resides in the default VPC.
To connect to it, i am using different EC2 instances (Java Spring Boot and NodeJs) running in ElasticBeanstalk. These instances also reside in the default VPC.
Do these EC2 instances connect to/query the RDS instance through the internet or the calls do not leave the AWS Network?
If they leave the AWS network and the calls go through the internet, is creating a VPC endpoint the right solution? Or my whole understanding is incorrect.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do these EC2 instances connect to/query the RDS instance through the internet or the calls do not leave the AWS Network?

The DNS of the RDS endpoint will resolve to **private IP** address when used from within VPC. So communication is **private**, even if you use public subnets or set your RDS instance as publicly available. However, for connection from outside of AWS, the RDS endpoint will resolve to public IP address if the db instance is publicly available.

> If they leave the AWS network and the calls go through the internet, is creating a VPC endpoint the right solution?

There is **no VPC endpoint for RDS client connections**, only for management actions (creating db-instance, termination, etc). In contrast, Aurora Serverless has Data API with corresponding VPC endpoint.

Comment: My DB instance is publicly accessible (for some management purposes). But from your clarification, it means that i do not need to use VPC endpoint and the connections from the EC2 instances will resolve to the private IP address and do not leave the VPC (even though i would have specific the public URL for the RDS in the application config/property files). Is that correct? Thanks a lot in advance @Marcin

Comment: @AleksandarT That's correct. You can check it using `dig <db-endpoint>` command if you want to make sure which IP is returned when queried from an instance, and what is returned when you `dig`  from outside of aws. If your DB is publicly available, please make sure to properly set it security groups to only your external IP, rather then `0.0.0.0/0` and `sg-of-the-instance` as to not to block connections from your instance. For ultimate security, it would be best to place rds in private subnet and use vpn from outside.

Answer (score 0):

To secure your DB-Instances communications you need to be sure at least about the following:

- locate your RD in private subnet (route table does not contain default outbound route to internet gateway).
- RDS security group just accept traffic inbound only from instances security group/groups on TCP port for PostgreSQL which is usually 5432.

In this case Traffice to RDS will go localy in your vpc, for vpc endpoints it can be used to access RDS API operations privatly which is not your case (you just need to connect your app to DB using connection string)